# Set parent to single custom post (breadcrumbs problem)

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have custom post type "gallery". I created custom page-gallery.php and single-gallery.php.

How can I set parent (page-gallery) to single-gallery?

I just want to Unyson breadcrumbs work like: "Home/Gallery/Album1", but when I go to single gallery it works like: "Home/Album1"

Comment: Checkout [Milo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94820/76745)`s answer here [wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94820/76745](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/94820/76745)

Comment: When I add `rewrite => array('slug' => 'gallery/%gallery%')` permalinks is changing into "Home/gallery/album1/album1" (album is copying). But when I add function (with changed word 'course' to my 'gallery') an error occurs: `Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array`